# How to find the limit of $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(cos^{(\frac{1}{x})})$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

**Question**

How Would i find the limit of:

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}(cos(e)^{(\frac{1}{x})})$

Because graphically it goes from 1 to -1 and when you zoom in you wouldn't get a real limit. Would this be indeterminate?

*Part B of question*

What is the difference between an answer that is undefined and in determinant?

Comment: That is good reasoning for why the limit doesn't exist.  I wouldn't say indeterminate since that term is more commonly associated with other kinds of limits.  A limit that is undefined or does not exist is on that does not get arbitrarily close to any number.  A limit that is indeterminate is one of the forms you learned in class.  Usually of the form $0/0$ or $\infty / \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=\cos e^{\frac1x}$ is oscillating infinitely as $x$ approaches $0$ from the right side. Therefore, the right-sided limit is undefined. The left-sided limit is $1$.

Undefined means that nothing is possible; indeterminate means that everything is possible. $\frac10$ is undefined; $\frac00$ is indeterminate. $1$ is not divisible by $0$, no matter how large the quotient; $0$ is divisible by $0$, but the quotient can be any value.

The basic indeterminate is $\infty-\infty$. If $f(x) = x+1$ and $g(x) = x$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-g(x)) = 1$. However, if $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-g(x)) = \infty$. In both cases, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) = \infty$.

Note: To find the limit of $\frac00$, $\frac\infty\infty$ and $0\cdot\infty$, you can try using L'Hôpital's rule. An important limit is $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x$. The graph of $y=\frac{\sin x}x$ has a hole $(0,1)$ ($y$ is undefined at $x=0$), but as $x$ approaches $0$ (on either side), $y$ goes to $1$. The limit is $1$.